# window is not scrolling smoothly - angulajs jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, scrollbar

I have one div (id='image-map-pro-container) that contains one siteplan which is collection of base image + many small images. Many of these images are combined through Image Library.

When I access this page on the server, after everything is loaded properly, scroll bar is not scrolling through the window smoothly. There is considerable lag.

Even after putting buttons like Scroll to Bottom and Scroll to Top, scrolling is not smooth and its lagged.

Please review the page and provide me with your suggestion to improve scrolling experience.

URL : http://54.225.18.101:8081/community/hideSidebar

Code for scrolling :

```
$('#btnClickTop').click(function(){                
            $('#image-map-pro-container').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 100, function(){
                $('#btnClickTop').hide(); 
                $('#btnClickBottom').show();
            });

        })
        $('#btnClickBottom').click(function(){
            $('#image-map-pro-container').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 1080
            }, 100, function(){
                $('#btnClickTop').show(); 
                $('#btnClickBottom').hide();    
            });                
        })
```

TIA.

Comment: IMO if you have a performance problem you should precise what browser / device you are using

Comment: My initial guess would be that something is causing the $digest cycle to run infinitely, crippling the app.

Comment: On Windows 10 / Firefox the page takes ages to load, but the scroll is very quick and has no lag